# ASP.NET - How to set Cells-Width-Percentage on C# Table

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, webforms

Hellooo, everyone! I have a **System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table** with cells(controls) with Width (20% by default). I want to change this Percentage -> 40% / 20% / 20% / 10% / 10%

**I want following:**

[image]

How  to set different **Width** on this cells(controls)?

**This is my code:**

```
Table myTbl = new Table();
TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();

    //Row1 Cells Controls

            TextBox txt11 = new TextBox();
            txt11.ID = "txtDest11";
            txt11.Height = 19;
           //txt11.Width = Unit.Percentage(40);

            TextBox txt12 = new TextBox();
            txt12.ID = "txtKmInCity12";
            txt12.Height = 19;

            TextBox txt13 = new TextBox();
            txt13.ID = "txtKmOutCity13";
            txt13.Height = 19;

            DateTimeControl dt11 = new DateTimeControl();
            dt11.DateOnly = true;
            dt11.ShowWeekNumber = true;
            dt11.LocaleId = 1026;

            DateTimeControl dt12 = new DateTimeControl();
            dt12.DateOnly = true;
            dt12.ShowWeekNumber = true;
            dt12.LocaleId = 1026;

            tRow1 = new TableRow();
            tRow1.Visible = true;

            TableCell tCellZero = new TableCell();
            tCellZero.Controls.Add(rowNo);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellZero);

            TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
            tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt11);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellOne);

            TableCell tCellTwo = new TableCell();
            tCellTwo.Controls.Add(dt11);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellTwo);

            TableCell tCellThree = new TableCell();
            tCellThree.Controls.Add(dt12);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellThree);

            TableCell tCellFour = new TableCell();
            tCellFour.Controls.Add(txt12);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellFour);

            TableCell tCellFive = new TableCell();
            tCellFive.Controls.Add(txt13);
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellFive);

            myTbl.Rows.Add(tRow1);
```

**Result :**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add width to `TableCell` instead. Use this:

```
TableCell myTableCell = new TableCell();
myTableCell.Width = new Unit("25%");
```

OR

```
myTableCell.Style.Add("width", "25%");
```

**UPDATE:**

For textboxes:

```
TextBox txt11 = new TextBox();
txt11.ID = "txtDest11";
txt11.Height = 19;
txt11.Style.Add("width", "100%");
```

For TableCells:

```
TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
 tCellOne.Style.Add("width", "40%");
 tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt11);
 tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellOne);
```

Comment: @Gohyu, you've mentioned `Width (20% by default)` in OP. Have you set width of textbox or tablecell? Where did you set the width (aspx or code-behind)?

Comment: On textbox in tablecell

Comment: I have not set anything to the width.

Comment: So it means each `TableCell` has 20% width. And you need to set width  in percentage of each `Textbox` contained in individual `TableCell`?

Comment: @Gohyu, Check my update to see if helps. Basically, set width for both `tablecell` and `textbox`.